# HEXADECIMAL VALUE 0X03 is an invalid character

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4, character-encoding

This is the source of a web page

```
<html lang="pl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<p>Da&#32;brow&#35;a G�rn&#x3;icza<p>

</body>

</html>
```

I need to browse this page and copy the text shown

[image: the text to be copied]

After that, I have pasted this text into an input text box of an asp.net mvc application in order to create a new record into the database. 
The meta charset of the layout page is "utf-8"

If I go to Visual Studio 2013 in debug, when the create action of the controller is executed, I can see the following string

[image: this is the address in debug mode]

This address has stored into a column of type nvarchar(255), and from sql management tool I see the same text as seen before:

[image: this is the address from the database]

If I copy and paste the address from database column to notepad++ I can see
[image]

After that I have to call a svc service in order to send the address data but I am receiving from the other side this exception

> ERROR TRANSFORMING XML '' HEXADECIMAL VALUE 0X03 is an invalid
>   character.

How can I avoid this exception being thrown ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x03` is simply ***not an [allowed character in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets)*** :

> ```
> [2] Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
> ```

*Therefore your textual object is not XML*, and any conformant XML processor is obliged to report an error such as the one you received.

You must repair the data by treating it as ***text, not XML,*** manually or automatically before using it with any XML libraries.

Comment: Do you mean with <![CDATA[]]> ?

Comment: `0x03` is `^C` aka `ETX` (end of transmission).   Consider deleting it altogether.