# Serializing and Deserializing strings containing Hex characters

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am reading this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6yBnhBColRmWGRWZWRWbnVITlk/view?usp=sharing) and using the [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to serialize and deserialize.  Sorry I am unable to post the contents of the file in this question as StackOverflow is encoding them incorrectly.

The Deserialize function is throwing an exception.

> '', hexadecimal value 0x03, is an invalid character. Line 5, position 20.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code. Also Available [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/b29091ab48958e57d4e4e1bd053a5cc7)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XMLTester
{
    public class HexTester
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\HexText.txt"); ;

            var foo = new Foo()
            {
                Items = new List<FooBar>()
                {
                    new FooBar()
                    {                            
                        Text = lines[0]                        
                    }
                }
            };

            string xml = SerializeToXML(foo);
            var objTabs = DeserializeFromXML(xml, typeof(Foo)); //This throws an error
        }

        static string SerializeToXML(object obj)
        {
            StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter(xml);
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
            textWriter.Close();

            return xml.ToString();
        }

        static object DeserializeFromXML(string xml, Type toType)
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(toType);
            TextReader textReader = new StringReader(xml);

            Object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(textReader); //This throws an error
            textReader.Close();

            return obj;
        }

    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public List<FooBar> Items { get; set; }
    }
    public class FooBar
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the point of serializing a text file?

Comment: I just get object Foo passed to my function. I gave the example to read from the file as StackOverflow was not allowing me to post the characters directly.

Comment: i tested your code. i think the issue lies in the **file**. if you download the file directly you'll see invisible characters. if I copy the contents from google drive then the program has no exceptions.

Comment: I know that the characters in the file are issue. That's the reason I posted this question. I dont want to use the characters that Google Drive is showing. I want to use the original file. Do you think encoding the characters differently will work?

Comment: do you mean you want to serialize any binary file? i think you can convert to   and from base64 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

0x03 ([End-of-Text character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Text_character)) is simply [not an allowed character in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36308069/7988857).

So you will need to [clean the invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322933) before you serialize or deserialize.

Comment: Do you think encoding the characters differently will work?

Comment: I agree 0x03 is not an allowed character in XML. But I am looking for a way to Serialize that into a valid character. Do you you have any inputs on that? Can I encode the string differently before Serializing?

Comment: @CodingDawg : How about getting the serialized xml text to be enclosed in a [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section (_like <Text><![CDATA[invalid_text]]></Text>_) with [XmlDocument.CreateCDataSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createcdatasection.aspx). Have a look at [serialize a string as CDATA using XmlSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1380050/7988857).

Comment: The input that I receive is dynamic. enclosing in the CDATA section will not be viable.

Comment: @CodingDawg : How about [converting the text to a base64 string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8170810/7988857) before serializing and after you deserialize you just [Convert.FromBase64String](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7134853/7988857) back to regular text.